# Cannot seem to get valid RSS feed for existing facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, rss

Do I need to do something extra to get the RSS for a "fan page"? Repeat, this is not a personal page, it is a "page", similar to how [example] https://www.facebook.com/georgehtakei is a page and not a personal login.

I am following the thousands of examples for getting the RSS url for a facebook fan page, and even with the proper ID I am receiving the following error.... (I have censored out the various ids for privacy purposes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:activity="http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com" xmlns:access="http://www.bloglines.com/about/specs/fac-1.0">
  <access:restriction relationship="allow" />
  <id>http://www.facebook.com/feeds/syndication_error.php#8fda6ce86f0e4d375d0eb33d8df4c50e</id>
  <generator uri="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook Syndication</generator>
  <!-- SUDA was here.  [Censored] -->
  <title></title>
  <link href="" />
  <link rel="self" href="https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&amp;id=[censored]" />
  <updated>2013-01-15T13:57:30-08:00</updated>
  <icon>http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico</icon>
  <logo>https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yk/r/GcJ2sQocxsN.png</logo>
  <entry>
    <title><![CDATA[Facebook Syndication Error]]></title>
    <id>http://www.facebook.com/feeds/syndication_error.php#8fda6ce86f0e4d375d0eb33d8df4c50e_</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.facebook.com/feeds/syndication_error.php#8fda6ce86f0e4d375d0eb33d8df4c50e_" />
    <published>2013-01-15T13:57:30-08:00</published>
    <updated>2013-01-15T13:57:30-08:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Facebook.com</name>
      <uri>http://www.facebook.com</uri>
    </author>
    <summary>This feed URL is no longer valid. Visit this page to find the new URL, if you have access: &amp;lt;a href=&amp;quot;https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[censored]&amp;quot;&amp;gt;https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[censored]&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;</summary>
    <content type="html"><![CDATA[This feed URL is no longer valid. Visit this page to find the new URL, if you have access: &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[censored]&quot;&gt;https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[censored]&lt;/a&gt;]]></content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Even using the http://graph.facebook.com/[url] doesn't work. I get the following error.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no geographic or demographic restrictions in place on the page? You'll need a logged-in user session to access it if there are

Comment: Is there anything I can do if there are such restrictions?

Comment: Yes, use a user access token from a user who meets the restrictions to retrieve the posts via the API, or look at them while logged into Facebook

Comment: I will try to find some documentation on that. Do you know where I can find any info on it right off hand?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/